# ember view helper not working in latest ember from master

Tags: ember.js

i have a simple text field helper, taken directly from the ember contact example. it works properly in this jsfiddle, using ember-0.9.8.1 : http://jsfiddle.net/inconduit/dKsh3/2/

however when i try to run the same code using the latest ember built from master (v0.9.8.1-421-g189ad79), the content of the text fields never get set (they remain as empty) and double clicking them has no effect.  why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's a context issue. You have to prefix the properties in the templates with "view".

See this modified JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dKsh3/4/